# Reading from a sequence file placed in DistributedCache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How can I read sequence files from distributed cache?

I have tried some things, but I'm always getting FileNotFoundException.

I'm adding file to distributed cache like this

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(currentMedoids), conf);
```

And reading from it in mapper's setup method

```
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path[] paths = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);

        List<Element> sketch = new ArrayList<Element>();

        SequenceFile.Reader medoidsReader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, paths[0], conf);

        Writable medoidKey = (Writable) medoidsReader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
        Writable medoidValue = (Writable) medoidsReader.getValueClass().newInstance();

        while(medoidsReader.next(medoidKey, medoidValue)){

            ElementWritable medoidWritable = (ElementWritable)medoidValue;
            sketch.add(medoidWritable.getElement());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I should have used getCacheFiles(), which returns URI[] instead of getLocalCacheFiles(), which returns Path[].

Now it works after making that change.